# Logstash convert array of objects into array of terms

Tags: arrays, logstash

***EDIT*** -> I created a plugin for this, available here:

- https://rubygems.org/gems/logstash-filter-collect
- https://github.com/mikebski/logstash-filter-collect

You can install with `bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-collect`
I have a logstash entry like:

```
 "cvals" => [
            [0] {
                   "text" => "cval something 1",
                "indices" => [
                    [0] 17,
                    [1] 29
                ]
            },
            [1] {
                   "text" => "cval something else 2",
                "indices" => [
                    [0] 17,
                    [1] 29
                ]
            }
            ...
            [n] {
                "text" => "cval more stuff n",
                "indices" => [
                    [0] 17,
                    [1] 29
                ]
            }

        ]
```

I would like to mutate it to be:

```
"cvals_terms" => [ "cval something 1", "cval something else 2", ..., "cval more stuff n"]
```

How do I do this with Logstash?  I could do it with a block of Ruby code, but there has to be a way to do it with mutate or something I think...

Answer (score 0):

Using logstash-oss v6.3.0, the following should work:

```
filter {
  ruby {
    code => "event.set('cvals_terms', event.get('cvals').map{ |n| n['text'] })"
  }
}
```

The downside is that you're coding in strings, which will hurt maintainability on the long run.

Comment: See the plugins in my original post, no need for custom code now.

Comment: This one-liner is provided as an alternative approach for people who seek a lightweight solution. Great job on the plugin though!

Comment: For moving Ruby code outside of Logstash pipeline, see also: https://www.elastic.co/blog/moving-ruby-code-out-of-logstash-pipeline